# chroot - networking doesn't work for apt-get

Tags: networking, apt, android, chroot, groups

I'm trying to set up `chroot` enviroment inside of Android (6.0). I (think) i set right groups and permissions and i have networking inside of my `chroot`, but for some reason `apt-get` is not able to connect to the servers (temporary failure resolving 'address).

I can manually download packages that I want with wget from those websites, so it's not a matter of broken DNS or anything. I can ping, i can wget, i just can't get package list from `apt-get update` - and of course, addresses in `/etc/apt/sources.list` are correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well can you post the actual output/error that you get when you run `apt-get update`? Also, please post the output of `ping -c4 google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble accessing your network after chroot, you probably use DHCP and can work around this by adding OpenDNS name servers to your /etc/resolv.conf after you use chroot:

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

In the open file, add OpenDNS name servers

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not it. As i said already, my DNS are set properly. Ping works, wget works, my DNSes are google ones so it's

(nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4)

I also have full permissions to manage wlan interface, i can open/close it and set it up from chroot.