# Install network-manager on Ubuntu14.04.4 LTS using live CD or any means

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, dpkg

Recently we removed systemd-services which removed many packages from System.  I tried to fix using live CD but couldn't get working. 
Output of `apt-get install  network-manager`

```
root@ubuntu:/var/cache/apt/archives# apt-get install network-manager -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 network-manager : Depends: libnl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libnl-route-3-200 (>= 3.2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: wpasupplicant (>= 0.7.3-1)
                   Recommends: crda
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@ubuntu:/var/cache/apt/archives#
```

How we can solve this problem. I have found there are many packages which seem to broken have a look on http://pastebin.com/fZt3FrTX

Comment: Please, can you add the output of  **apt-get -f install** ?

Comment: I looked at the pastebin. Why do you think that those are broken?

Comment: @Anwar Not all of them. Since they have information like breaks/conflicts.

Comment: @ManuelAlvarez no useful since don't have the internet.

Comment: Have you tried going to [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3) on another computer and download all binary packages from the "Binary packages built by this source" and then copied them to a USB stick and copy them to the defunct computer and then install?

Comment: @Fabby Tried but no luck. Problem is that the installed packages version are conflicting with required packages version.

Comment: @sonukumar you can even configure your network to connect to the internet without the networkmanager, and then you can try to fix your networkmanager more effectively.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f libnl-3-200`? That should get us closer to the reason why the installation of the dependant `network-manager` fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few options that may work:

- If you have possibility to connect wired interface.

  1. Check interface name (ex `eth0`)

     ```
     sudo ifconfig -a
     ```
  2. Connect using DHCP client

     ```
     sudo dhclient eth0
     ```
  3. Install needed packages
- Live CD does not have a packages archive (in `pool` folder), so:

  1. Boot with live CD
  2. Either download `dpkg-repack` and repack the need packages then reboot and install them.

     Or copy their installed files manually: get list using `dpkg -L <packagename>` then reboot and fix the dpkg status using `sudo dpkg --audit; sudo dpkg configure -a`

Comment: There's no eth0 interface.

Comment: @sonukumar in that case, if you please give us a paste of `ifconfig -a`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes what I do if I have broken dependencies like these seem to be is to uninstall the dependencies and re-install them manually.

Since you have no internet connection what you could do if you have access to a live USB is to boot the live USB, use that to connect to the internet and re-install network-manager and the dependencies to your actual system from there. This would solve the problem of having no internet due to the lack of network-manager. See Serg's answer on the following linked post and apply it to re-installing the broken dependencies as well as network-manager.

[I accidentally deleted the network-manager and don't have access to internet anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652401/i-accidentally-deleted-the-network-manager-and-dont-have-access-to-internet-any)

Hope this helps!

Comment: No success. Can't install network manager due to broken packages.

Comment: Do you know which packages are broken? If so you might be able to (using the live USB) remove and reinstall the broken packages. I would recommend running "apt purge" instead of "apt remove" as it would remove the configuration files as well. Then reinstall the packages and repeat this until all the broken packages and the dependencies for network-manager are installed and are not broken. Then try re-installing network-manager. For example run "apt purge libnl-3-200" to remove it and then "apt install libnl-3-200" to reinstall it. Hopefully this works.

Comment: There are many as given in Pastebin link.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, assuming you still have the required kernel modules for eth0 you should be able to run sudo ifconfig eth0 / up to bring up the network.  Here is an example of that

sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.13.14/24 up

If that fails it'll be fairly obvious.  You may want to run ifconfig -a to list all interfaces to find the right one, if eth0 isn't it.  You may also specify the newmask directly as in

sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.13.14 netmask 255.255.255.0

Once you've got that there, you can add a gateway route to get you on the internet using

sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 192.168.13.1

I would check your /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d and run sudo apt-get update to ensure you have the right list

Once you have a network connection and an update packages list, you may want to use dpkg -l  to see what's installed and use dpkg -r  or dpkg -P  to remove packages, before reinstalling them with apt-get.

Also check you're not out of disk space.  I find that on servers that remain untouched for a while they tend to download lots of kernel updates,  without autopurging old ones that have never been used.  Once you're out of disk space apt-get remove can be problematic too, so use uname -a to check which kernel you're running and use dpkg -P  to remove anything other than that.