# accidently deleted wpa_supplicant

Tags: internet, wpa-supplicant

I accidently deleted wpa_supplicant package and now I cant connect to the internet, not through wifi and not through LAN cable.
What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: anybody? please

Answer (score 1):

I recently found myself in the same situation. The answer is actually out there, but it's spread all over the internet

I had to do multiple different google searches( with multiple different keywords ) and go through dozens of different questions, on different forums, on the SAME TOPIC.

Finally, i was able to solve the problem, but had to go through a frustating process, this is very difficult for Linux Newbies, who like to play around with little or no knowledge( like me )

This was posted about a month ago and you probably solved it by now,

I'm gonna answer this anyways, It'll atleast make it easier for people who faces this very problem in the future:)

---

**STEP 1 : getting acces to internet via ethernet cable**

open your terminal and run this command

`iwconfig`

to find out the name of your ethernet device.
the output will look something like this...

```
wlp2s0f0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"LYF"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: DC:E8:38:61:A4:50   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:36  Invalid misc:76   Missed beacon:0

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

in older versions of ubuntu, the wifi device will usually be named `wlan0` and the eternet ( LAN cable ) will probably be named as `eth0` ( or something like that )

but now, in 16.04 ( my ubuntu version ) the names are device specific. in my case they're `wlp2s0f0` and `enp4s0` for wifi and eternet decices, respectively.

---

run this command to get your eternet device up and running...

```
sudo dhclient enp4s0 up
```

you can check by running

```
curl www.google.com
```

if it didn't work then your'll get a resolution error,

if it did work then you'll get some html code, ( this is just to see if the connection is OK )

***NOTE : if `step 1` is UNsuccesfull, then skip to `step 3`***

---

**STEP 2 : re-installing wpasupplicant via apt-get**

run the command

```
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

***NOTE : if `step 2` is succesfull, then you can skip `step 3`***

---

**STEP 3 : re-installing wpasupplicant manually ( if step 1 failed )**

When you remove a certain package, you also remove all of it's dependencies and probably configuration files too ( is you "accidentally"  purged it )

I'm assuming that you have a debian based distro ( ubuntu is a debian based linux distro ),

if you do, then download the .deb files from here...

https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/wpasupplicant

you might also need another 2 files which are dependencies of wpasupplicant, you'll find them here...

https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libengine-pkcs11-openssl

and here...

https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libp11-2

after downloading them,

navigate to the folder where you downloaded them ( remember, all 3 files should be in the same folder ) and run

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

***NOTE : if `step 1` failed, then after `step 3` you should be able to succesfully connect to the internet via the LAN cable***

---

**STEP 4 : putting the peices together**

you're going to have to link all the components together, you can do that by,

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

this command will download and install any missing files ( such as network-manager, gnome-indicator, etc ) that might have also been accidentally removed.
also, it'll update all the packages to the latest version

---

STEP 5 : reboot for changes to take effect

run this command in the terminal

```
shutdown -r now
```

---

you should be able to connect to the internet via wifi and enternet after this.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't ask why, but I also accidentally removed this and managed to find myself in the same situation. Since I am a total newbie as well and the above-described solution did not work perfectly in my case, I just wanted to share what I had to do to be able to connect to the internet as well.**

1. Firstly, this link: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/wpasupplicant does not work anymore. I get this error: "two or more packages specified (wpasupplicant wheezy)."
2. I am using Ubuntu 20.04, so this was the website I needed at the end: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/wpasupplicant.
3. I checked all the dependencies I did not have with the following command: `dpkg -s "package name"`.
4. I downloaded all the packages where the command gave back "installed ok unpacked" or "nothing found."
5. Since there are several different download links, I had to check which architecture my system had with the following command: `dpkg --print-architecture`. This gave back "amd64," so I knew I had to download that version of all the packages.
6. I ended up downloading the following packages:

   - `wpasupplicant 2:2.9-1`
   - `libssl1.1`
   - `libpcsclite1`
   - `libengine-pkcs11-openssl`
   - `wpagui`
7. I copied them to the PC without internet and installed them with the above-mentioned command: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.
8. Then I restarted the system, but in Settings/Network, I got the following error: "Network manager is missing."
9. So now I tried to install it with the following command: `sudo apt-get install network-manager`.
10. Of course, it gave back an error:

```
    sudo apt-get install network-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dns-root-data dnsmasq-base libndp0 libteamdctl0 network-manager-pptp ppp pptp-linux
Suggested packages:
  libteam-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed
  dns-root-data dnsmasq-base libndp0 libteamdctl0 network-manager network-manager-pptp ppp pptp-linux
0 to upgrade, 8 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 2.598 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9.972 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 dns-root-data all 2019052802
Ign:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 dnsmasq-base amd64 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.7
Err:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libndp0 amd64 1.7-0ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
Err:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libteamdctl0 amd64 1.30-1
  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
Err:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 network-manager amd64 1.22.10-1ubuntu2.3
  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
Ign:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ppp amd64 2.4.7-2+4.1ubuntu5.1
Err:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 pptp-linux amd64 1.10.0-1build1
  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
Err:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 network-manager-pptp amd64 1.2.8-2
  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
Err:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 dns-root-data all 2019052802
  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 dnsmasq-base amd64 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.7
  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ppp amd64 2.4.7-2+4.1ubuntu5.1
  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dns-root-data/dns-root-data_2019052802_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dnsmasq/dnsmasq-base_2.80-1.1ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libndp/libndp0_1.7-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libteam/libteamdctl0_1.30-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_1.22.10-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/ppp/ppp_2.4.7-2+4.1ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pptp-linux/pptp-linux_1.10.0-1build1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager-pptp/network-manager-pptp_1.2.8-2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving ‘de.archive.ubuntu.com’
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

11. I downloaded all these .deb files manually, copied them to the PC without internet, and installed them with the same command I used to install the wpasupplicant and its dependencies: `dpkg -i *.deb`.
12. And voila, everything was working again as it should be.